# [Bitbucket][Pipelines] Get the name of the user who launched the pipeline

Tags: continuous-integration, bitbucket, pipeline, bitbucket-pipelines

tengo creado un pipeline de CI/CD con Bitbucket Pipelines. Dentro del archivo bitbucket-pipelines.yml defini un custom pipe. Ej:

```
  custom:
    manual-deploy:
      - step:
          name: Manuel Deploy
          services:
            - docker
          caches:
            - maven
          script:
              - echo "Deploy..."
```

I need to get the username or nickname of the user who triggered a custom step. How can I do this?

I read in the documentation that the variable BITBUCKET_STEP_TRIGGERER_UUID exists, but I don't know how to identify which user this UUID belongs to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the $BITBUCKET_STEP_TRIGGERER_UUID to resolve the actual username the following way:

```
export BITBUCKET_TRIGGERER_USERNAME=$(curl -X GET -g "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/users/${BITBUCKET_STEP_TRIGGERER_UUID}" | jq --raw-output '.display_name')
```

I found the answer in one of the comments here: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-16711